# re How to insert dynamic data (HTML) into SendGrid Templates

Tags: sendgrid

Can variable data be inserted into another variable in sendgrid?

For example I have an html variable called {{{description}}} can the information that is passed into description be a combination of static and dynamic data like "hello {{{firstname}}}"

When I try to do this it is passing the literal {{{firstname}}} instead of the actual first name.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a dynamic template with a variable inside the template the variable value can be whatever you want it to be. I don't know how your using Sendgrid (api or sdk) but with their API the way you structure the post data contains the variable values so you can say description = hello whatever you want

heres an example of the the piece of the post data to sendgrid api

```
'dynamic_template_data' => array(
    'description' => "Hello " . $first_name
),
```